# Utilizando la libreria Javax.mail. El correo que se envia se triplica

Tags: java, email

Buen día,

Estoy haciendo un proceso de notificación vía email y estoy utilizando la librería javax.mail, la lógica ya esta hecha y envía el correo. Pero cuando se envía el primer correo 1 min después llega otro correo igual anterior y luego dos min después llega otro. En total 3 correos con la misma información. Dejo el código con el cual se esta realizando el envío.

Estoy utilizado Java 8 con JPA y hibernate. el motor de base de datos es mysql.

```
private void enviarCorreo(List<SegParametrosConfiguracion> parametros, String excelArchivo, List<FacturaEncabezado> facturas) {

    logger.info("Inicia metodo para realizar el envío de correos con el resumen de transacciones diarias");

    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    SegParametrosConfiguracion password = parametros.stream().filter(x -> x.getNombreParametro().equals("Password")).findFirst().orElse(null);

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", obtenerValorParametro(parametros, "Host"));  //El servidor SMTP de Google
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", obtenerValorParametro(parametros, "EmailFrom"));    // Email del remitente
    props.put("mail.smtp.clave", CriptografiaUtils.MD5Desencriptar("MamboErrp",
            new String(password.getValorParametro())));    //La clave de la cuenta
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", obtenerValorParametro(parametros, "Auth"));    //Usar autenticación mediante usuario y clave
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", obtenerValorParametro(parametros, "Tls")); //Para conectar de manera segura al servidor SMTP
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", obtenerValorParametro(parametros, "Port")); //El puerto SMTP seguro de Google

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();
    BodyPart adjunto = new MimeBodyPart();
    MimeMultipart multiParte = new MimeMultipart();

    String cantFacturas = getCantidadFacturasXTipoDocumento(facturas);

    try {
        texto.setText("Buen día, \n\nSe adjunta reporte de transacciones diarias de la compañía " + password.getIdCompania().getNombreCompania() + ". Las transacciones hechas por los distintos tipos de comprobantes fueron: \n\n" + cantFacturas + " \n SISTEMA POS");// Se compone la parte del texto

        // Se compone el adjunto con la imagen
        adjunto.setDataHandler(
                new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(excelArchivo)));
        adjunto.setFileName("ResumenTransaccionesDiarias.xlsx");

        // Una MultiParte para agrupar texto e imagen.
        multiParte.addBodyPart(texto);
        multiParte.addBodyPart(adjunto);

    } catch (Throwable th) {
        logger.error("ERROR AL AGREGAR EL ADJUNTO => " + th.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException("ERROR AL AGREGAR EL ADJUNTO NO SE ENVIAN CORREOS: " + th.getMessage());
    }

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    List<GenCorreosNotificar> correosNotificar = resumenTransaccionDiariaService.getCorreosNotificar(password.getIdCompania().getIdCompania());
    if (correosNotificar.size() > 0) {
        logger.info("Se encontraron " + correosNotificar.size() + " destinatarios");
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(password.getValorParametro()));
            for (GenCorreosNotificar correo : correosNotificar) {
                Address toAddress = new InternetAddress(correo.getCorreo());
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);   //Se podrían añadir varios de la misma manera   
            }
            message.setSubject("Resumen Transacciones Diarias - " + password.getIdCompania().getNombreCompania());
            message.setText("Se adjunta envía transacciones diarias de la compañía " + password.getIdCompania().getNombreCompania());
            message.setContent(multiParte);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport(obtenerValorParametro(parametros, "Transport"));
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", obtenerValorParametro(parametros, "EmailFrom"),
                    CriptografiaUtils.MD5Desencriptar("MamboErrp", new String(password.getValorParametro())));
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            logger.info("Finaliza metodo para realizar el envío de correos con el resumen de transacciones diarias");
        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            logger.error("ERROR AL ENVIAR CORREOS => " + me.getMessage());
            logger.info("Finaliza metodo para realizar el envío de correos con el resumen de transacciones diarias");
            me.printStackTrace();   //Si se produce un error            
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("No se encuentran destinarios para realizar los envíos. Validar los destinatarios de la compañia " + password.getIdCompania().getIdCompania() + " - " + password.getIdCompania().getNombreCompania());
        logger.info("Finaliza metodo para realizar el envío de correos con el resumen de transacciones diarias");
    }
}
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿Has comprobado? A: Cuántas direcciones de correo (y cuales) te llegan a `correosNotificar` y B: Si llamas a este código varias veces.

Comment: @Jorgesys Agradezco tu respuesta. Si valide ese tema pero enviando solo un recipiente también sucede lo mismo. Pero me di cuenta que el proceso de notificación lo hace un hilo,   quite el hilo y no sucede esto. Lo que se me hace raro es que en el debug no llega a enviar correo por que el proceso de notificación se hace a una hora en especifico, si ya se ejecuta no entra al metodo de enviarCorreo().

Comment: hilo esta así: `@Override public void run() {  try { while (!stop) {                       
 logger.info("Inicio de Hilo para realizar las notificaciones de MAMBOERP");
iEnviarNotificaciones.enviarNotificaciones();
Thread.sleep(120000);
logger.info("Finaliza el Hilo para realizar las notificaciones de MAMBOERP");
            }
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            logger.error("Error Hilo Notificador fico => " + th.getMessage());
        }
    }   `

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una lista de objetos `GenCorreosNotificar`

```
 List<GenCorreosNotificar> correosNotificar = resumenTransaccionDiariaService.getCorreosNotificar(password.getIdCompania().getIdCompania());
```

si iteras sobre esta lista para agregar los recipientes, esa puede ser la causa por la cual se envían varios email, puedes imprimir el email del destinatario para que lo compruebes:

```
        for (GenCorreosNotificar correo : correosNotificar) {
            Logger.info("Se enviará correo a : " + correo.getCorreo()); //*Imprime destinatarios.
            Address toAddress = new InternetAddress(correo.getCorreo());
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);   //Se podrían añadir varios de la misma manera   
        }
```

Otra razón es que llames en más de una ocasión el método `enviarCorreo()`.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. Si valide ese tema pero enviando solo un recipiente también sucede lo mismo. Pero me di cuenta que el proceso de notificación lo hace un hilo, quite el hilo y no sucede esto. Lo que se me hace raro es que en el debug no llega a enviar correo por que el proceso de notificación se hace a una hora en especifico, si ya se ejecuta no entra al metodo de enviarCorreo(). –

Comment: hilo esta así: @Override public void run() {  try { while (!stop) {                         logger.info("Inicio de Hilo para realizar las notificaciones de MAMBOERP"); iEnviarNotificaciones.enviarNotificaciones(); Thread.sleep(120000); logger.info("Finaliza el Hilo para realizar las notificaciones de MAMBOERP");             }         } catch (Throwable th) {             logger.error("Error Hilo Notificador fico => " + th.getMessage());         }     }

Comment: no se como realizar el proceso de notificación con un hilo. sin que se repita el correo

Comment: ok, ya veo Jean Paul, estas seguro que si no lo realiza en un hilo se envia sin problema?

Comment: si JorgeSys el hilo es el que me genera ese doble envió itere un for con el proceso y no me sucede eso.

Comment: lo realice con una tarea programada y funciono bien. Lo malo es que lo necesito hacer con un Hilo.